# How can I position equation numbers always to the left side?

Tags: math-mode, equations, numbering, positioning

Equations and amsmath environments put equation numbers to the right side by default, the output of

```
\begin{multline}
  some equation
\end{multline}
```

is:

```
equation (number)
```

How can I change it this way:

```
(number) equation
```

Comment: do you want only the numbers left or also _all_ equations left aligned? The `multline` environment is by default left aligned with its first line but not the other environments, like `align`

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Pass the option `leqno` to your document class, to be used by the class and also inherited by packages, such as the `amsmath` package. It would already work if you would specify the option directly to `amsmath`, however for consistency I would already use it at class level.

```
\documentclass[leqno]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{multline}
  some equation
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

`leqno` means *left equation numbers*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Suppose I want to number only particular equations on the left (rest all in right), then how can I do so?

Comment: @AbhimanyuArora Bit late, but there's [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193535/switch-between-leqno-and-reqno-options-of-amsmath-in-the-same-document). Doesn't work properly for me since the numbering overlaps with the equation if it's too long, but it's a start.

Comment: Can it be set after `\documentclass`?