# Switch between leqno and reqno options (of amsmath) in the same document

Tags: equations, amsmath

I'd like to know if it is possible switch between the `leqno` and `reqno` options in the same document keeping the numbering of the equations. Namely i use the `reqno` option (default for `amsmath` and the standard `article` class), but i want that some equations are numbered by the left side (as if I had relied the `leqno` option) and the others no.

I'd like a commands as `\leqnomode` and `\reqnomode` to change the position of `\tag` in anywhere of the document.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here you go:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[leqno]{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\leqnomode}{\tagsleft@true}
\newcommand{\reqnomode}{\tagsleft@false}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
  g(x) &= dx^2 + ex + f
\end{align}

\reqnomode

\begin{align}
  f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
  g(x) &= dx^2 + ex + f
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What are these `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`?

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent: They are required when using `@` symbols in macros. See [What do `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` do?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/5764)

Comment: Is there a similar way of doing this with `equation` environment?

Comment: @Mappi: I can't see a way to achieve that right now. A work-around is to use `align`, even though it has only a single equation and doesn't require any form of `align`ment.

Comment: @Werner: I tried to use your code in a (long) document, and it suppresses the equation number instead of changing on which side it is written. Do you have any idea which packages might be incompatible?

Comment: @Mappi It's a tad late, but I'll leave this here for the convenience of anyone who is wondering about the solution for the `equation` environment. http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/212099/117534