# Tag placing with amsmath

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, numbering, amsmath

I'm using `amsmath` and its `\tag` command to tag equations. I remember having a situation where I liked having the tag on the left better than on the right. So I gave my class (which is `report` btw) the `leqno` options. Now, however, I find myself wanting to revert to `reqno`. However, I fear actually removing `leqno` will make the above mentioned situation look worse. I found that the solution in [Switch between leqno and reqno options (of amsmath) in the same document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193535/switch-between-leqno-and-reqno-options-of-amsmath-in-the-same-document) does not work with `equation`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[leqno]{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\leqnomode}{\tagsleft@true}
\newcommand{\reqnomode}{\tagsleft@false}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
  g(x) &= dx^2 + ex + f
\end{align}

\reqnomode

\begin{align}
  f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
  g(x) &= dx^2 + ex + f \tag{e}
\end{align}

\begin{equation}
  a^2+b^2=c^2.\tag{1}
\end{equation}

\leqnomode

\begin{equation}
  -\Delta\phi=4\pi k\rho.\tag{2}
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

The first `equation` should still be in `\reqnomode` (alias `\tagsleft@false`) from the second align, yet the tag is on the left. How do I solve the problem without using an `align` or such which are for multiline display and would therefore be out of place on a single one-line equation?

Comment: And yes, I should not use two `\[\]`s in a row, but rather use a multiline environment. I usually do, but that is an MWE so I kept it as short as possible.

Comment: @tohecz why is that so?

Comment: @tohecz OK, but the problem persists with `equation`.

Comment: Interesting. I cleaned up the question, I hope you don't mind, and voted for re-opening.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
\documentclass{report}


\usepackage[leqno]{amsmath}



\makeatletter
\newcommand{\leqnomode}{\tagsleft@true\let\veqno\@@leqno}
\newcommand{\reqnomode}{\tagsleft@false\let\veqno\@@eqno}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
  g(x) &= dx^2 + ex + f
\end{align}

\reqnomode

\begin{align}
  f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
  g(x) &= dx^2 + ex + f \tag{e}
\end{align}


\begin{equation}
  a^2+b^2=c^2.\tag{1}
\end{equation}


\leqnomode

\begin{equation}
  -\Delta\phi=4\pi k\rho.\tag{2}
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, that works @DavidCarlisle. Could you expand on why `\let\veqno\@@eqno` makes it work with `equation` and without that extra command it doesn't?

Comment: `equation` is really `$$` unlike `align` which is really a table with `$\displaystyle` in each cell. `\eqno` and `\leqno` are the tex primitives to set eqn numbers in `$$` amsmath sets `\veqno` to one or the other depending on `leqno` option @MickG