# Flush leftmost column to left in alignat

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, alignat, alignment

I'd like the (a) and (b) to be flushed to the left of the page, while "1+1=2" and "1+2=3" still remained aligned at the center of the page. What should I do?

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
(a) &  & 1+1 & =2.\\
(b) &  & 1+2 & =3.
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: use `\tag{(a)}` (or better just use `align` and let the automatic numbering add `(a)` and use the `leqno` package option so that comes on the left

Answer (score 1):

It looks like  what you actually want are custom equation numbers on the left. To archive this, you can give the `leqno` option to `amsmath` to put all equation numbers on the left. (If you also want some equation number on the right, [Tag placing with amsmath](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212085/tag-placing-with-amsmath) shows how to change this in some parts of a document.
Then you can set the actual number/character/tag with `\tag{...}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[leqno]{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
\tag{a} 1+1 & =2.\\
\tag{b} 1+2 & =3.
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to do this locally, i.e. for just one particular line in an alignat?

Comment: @dtcm840 Do you mean a single alignat with some tags on the left and some on the right?