# How to define switches for turning on and off the option `fleqn` of `amsmath`

Tags: amsmath

There are [switches for `amsmath` options `leqno` and `reqno`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/212099).

**Then, how to define switches for turning on and off the option `fleqn` after `amsmath` is loaded?**

---

I looked into the source of `amsmath.sty` and define the switches as

```latex
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\fleqnon}{\setboolean{@fleqn}{true}}
\newcommand*{\fleqnoff}{\setboolean{@fleqn}{false}}
\makeatother
```

These two switches work only when `amsmath` is loaded with the option `fleqn`.

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[b6paper]{scrartcl}

%\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}  % works with the option `fleqn`
\usepackage{amsmath}          % fails without the option `fleqn`
\usepackage{ifthen}

\makeatletter
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/212099
\newcommand*{\leqnomode}{\tagsleft@true\let\veqno=\@@leqno}
\newcommand*{\reqnomode}{\tagsleft@false\let\veqno=\@@eqno}
% based on my guess on `amsmath.sty`
\newcommand*{\fleqnon}{\setboolean{@fleqn}{true}}
\newcommand*{\fleqnoff}{\setboolean{@fleqn}{false}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\fleqnon

\begin{align}
  f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
  g(x) &= dx^2 + ex + f
\end{align}

\fleqnoff

\begin{align}
  f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
  g(x) &= dx^2 + ex + f \tag{e}
\end{align}

\fleqnon
\leqnomode

\begin{align}
  f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
  g(x) &= dx^2 + ex + f \tag{a}
\end{align}

\fleqnoff
\begin{align}
  f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
  g(x) &= dx^2 + ex + f
\end{align}

\begin{equation}
  a^2+b^2=c^2.
\end{equation}

\reqnomode

\begin{equation}
  -\Delta\phi=4\pi k\rho.\tag{2}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Assuming that there are reasons for doing this, why don't you simply load `amsmath` with the `fleqn` option, given that it works?

Comment: the package only defines flush left or centred layouts when the package is loaded, so you can not switch mid document without copying chunks of the package code for the other case, there is no simple switch.

Comment: @egreg Hmm, from my side there are several reasons for this question. Firstly, I am not sure whether the version based on my guess is correct. Secondly, there are switches for `leqno` and `reqno`, so it may be helpful to have one for `fleqn`.

Comment: @Eli4ph there are not really supported switches for `leqno` either. I think the answer that you link to is misleading, they work sometimes but not in general. I may fix that later....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The motivation behind is to achieve an enumeration of a list of display equations similar to inline math inside `enumerate` environment. Many answers on tex.sx use `fleqn` option. But I want other math not changed. That's why I want such switches.

Comment: The package is designed for the memory requirements of 1980s.... There simply wasn't room to define all four versions and have a switch to enable any of them mid-document.  It wouldn't be that hard these days to go through the package and every time it has a top level test such as `\iftagsleft@\if@fleqn` modify it so that the false branch is not skipped but instead saved in a macro that you could locally execute to change the choice locally, but that is not what the package does now.

Comment: Not exactly switches, but `nccmath` defines `fleqn` and `ceqn` environments, which work somewhat like `subequations`.

Answer (score 7):

The comments in `amsmath.dtx` say:

```
%    The code for calculating the appropriate placement of equation
%    tags in the \env{align} environments is quite complicated and
%    varies wildly depending on the settings of the |tagsleft@| and
%    |@fleqn| switches.  To minimize memory and hash space usage, we
%    only define the variant appropriate for the current setting of
%    those switches.
%
```

this means that of the four possible combinations of `fleqn` and `leqno` options being used or not used, definitions are made for only *one* combination, chosen at package loading time. The other three possibilities are skipped over and the TeX definitions for that combination are not made.

So if you change either of these switches mid document without copying code from the package sources and implementing the appropriate definitions, then the layout will basically be arbitrary and typically wrong, as you show.

Comment: Is there any way to center individual display math, at least unnumbered, while `fleqn` option was given? Is there something like `center` environment for math?

Comment: @Alexey `$$x=1$$`

Comment: Thanks, forgot about it. Is there a way that would work for `gather*` and `align*`?

Comment: @Alexey no, as I explain in this answer