# How to flush left and center different parts of math mode statement in one line

Tags: math-mode

How to write the line:

`(P) \sqrt{2} is irrational`

In math mode, if the `(P)` is to be at the beginning of the line and `\sqrt{2} is irrational` is to be in the middle of the line *(centered)*.

Comment: Is `(P)` some kind of label which should be referenced?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an `equation` environment and tag it with "P". To place the tag on the left, you can use `amsmath`'s `leqno` option, as in the following example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[leqno]{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\tag{P}
\sqrt{2} \text{ is irrational}.
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to use other `equation` environments in the same document and you want the tags placed on the right, you can use the method described in David Carlisle's answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/212099/201628), as in the following example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[leqno]{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\leqnomode}{\tagsleft@true\let\veqno\@@leqno}
\newcommand{\reqnomode}{\tagsleft@false\let\veqno\@@eqno}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\reqnomode
\begin{equation}
E = mc^2. 
\end{equation}
\leqnomode
\[
\tag{P}
\sqrt{2} \text{ is irrational}.
\]
\reqnomode
\begin{equation}
E = mc^2.
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]