# How to hide an equation's tag while still being able to cross reference it?

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, enumerate

I have the following,

```
\begin{equation}
\label{Hyp}\tag{$\mathbf{H}$}
\nonumber
(\mathbf{H})\left\{
\begin{tabular}{p{\textwidth}}
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\subscript{\mathbf{H}}{{\arabic*}})]
    \item something
    \item something
    \item something
\end{enumerate}
\end{tabular}
\right.
\end{equation}
```

But I don't want the equation to have the (H) tag showing in the document, I only want it to show as such when I am cross referencing, i.e., if i write \ref{Hyp} then I want (H).

Comment: Hello @TSF! Do you looking for something like [`autonum`](https://ctan.org/pkg/autonum) package? Be aware this package is not supported very long and other packages have difficulties to work with this package.

Comment: No, not quite. I know I will reference this equation and I want it to have a custom tag. However, this results in the custom tag showing up on the equation (in the bottom right) and this is undesirable. I want it to be a tagged equation without the tag showing up on the equation itself, and I want to be able to reference it as such.

Comment: Since you _are_ printing manually the tag on the left, would it be an option to switch to left equation numbering for this equation? You could then use simply https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/212099/82917

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't actually work for me as the placement of the tag isn't aligned correctly with the brace. Really would like to remove the automatic showing of the tag.

Comment: Please use `@username` to ping someone, otherwise the user gets no message. But to the point: the placement of the tag isn't aligned because you are forcing a tabular of width `\textwidth`. Your code will complain about an overfull `\hbox`. If you choose a reasonable size the tag will be correctly centered.

Comment: @campa I see, you're completely correct. Thanks for your help with this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could override the `amsmath` mechanism:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,enumitem}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\weirdlabel}[2]{%
  \protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\newlabel{#1}{{#2}{\thepage}}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-5]
\begin{equation*}
\weirdlabel{Hyp}{\ensuremath{\mathbf{H}}}
(\mathbf{H})\left\{
\begin{minipage}{0.8\textwidth}
  \begin{enumerate}[label=(\arabic*$_{\mathbf{H}}$)]
    \item \lipsum[2][1-5]
    \item \lipsum[2][6]
    \item \lipsum[2][7]
  \end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}
\right.
\end{equation*}
\lipsum[3]
\ref{Hyp}

\end{document}
```

As you see, the `\ref` command produces the expected **H**.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. In the end I went with Campa's suggestion of getting the tag on the left but if I had found this first I would have used it.