# Move Equation Numbering To Left in Beamer for Single Equation

Tags: beamer, equations, amsmath, tags

In a regular article using amsmath  or amsart I can move the equation tag to the left for a single equation by using \tagsleft@true immediately before the equation.  This doesn't seem to work in beamer.  How  can I move a single equation tag to the left side in beamer?

In particular when I try to run

```
\begin{frame}[t]
{\makeatletter
        \tagsleft@true
        \begin{equation}\tag{$\mathscr{P}_{i}$}
          x = y
        \end{equation}
\makeatother }
\end{frame}
```

I get Undefined control sequence \end{frame} and I don't get that error if I remove \tagsleft@true.

(Similar tips about replacing \setlength@mathmargin{1.5cm} and @fleqntrue in beamer would be appreciated too and I suspect these are all not working for the same reason).

Comment: Related https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212085/tag-placing-with-amsmath/212099#212099

Comment: Wild guess, not tested.  You might try moving the switch of side outside of the `frame`.  Of course, then you'd have to reset it after the `frame`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton thanks but the motivation is because I want to create a version of a special equation environment that works in beamer.  This equation environment moves the tag to the left but it may be mixed with other equations so that's not really a solution I can use here.

Comment: @PeterGerdes You can avoid the issues with using `\makeatletter ... \makeatother` inside the frame environment by using the custom `\leqnomode` macro from the duplicate question