# tag on the left in align environment

Tags: math-mode, align, labels, tag

in align environment, my tags are on the right, and that is fine. but in some paragraphs I'd want to put my tags on the left. How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SE :) // Please post (relevant part of) your code. Latex is complex, so more often than not there is no generic answer to "open" questions like yours wihtout seeing specific code ;-) Thanks

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/193538/263192 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/212099/263192

Answer (score 0):

Define `\leqnomode`, then use it locally.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\leqnomode}{\tagsleft@true\let\veqno\@@leqno}
%\newcommand{\reqnomode}{\tagsleft@false\let\veqno\@@eqno}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
  g(x) &= dx^2 + ex + f
\end{align}

\begin{equation}\leqnomode
  -\Delta\phi=4\pi k\rho.
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  a^2+b^2=c^2.
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way, please give a minimal working example when to ask a question next time to make others answer conveniently.