# The dual to the positioning of `\tag`?

Tags: positioning, amsmath

In an amsmath environment, the `\tag*` command is quite smart: If its argument fits on the same line, to the right of the formula, it goes there, otherwise it is moved to the next line; in both cases it is shoved to the very right.

I need a command that does the same, but in the opposite direction: If the argument fits on the left of the formula, it would be set there, otherwise it is moved to a line on its own *before* the formula; in both cases it would be shoved to the very left.

It is basically the behavior of `\tag` using the leqno option, but that does not help me, as I need both variants, sometimes on the same line.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: that is `\tag` if you specified `leqno` option to the document or `amsmath` package.

Comment: as david says, the `leqno` option will do it for the entire document; you should also use the `tbtags` option, otherwise the number will be set at the vertical center of a group.  but you don't say if you want this for the whole document, or only for selected displays -- which is it?

Comment: I didn’t know about `leqno`, thanks. I clarified the question accordingly.

Comment: @barbarabeeton not whole document (see comments below my answer)

Comment: for situations on which only one tag is placed on an equation, this question provides an answer: [Switch between leqno and reqno options (of amsmath) in the same document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/193535/579).  but putting two numbers on the same line is an entirely different kettle of fish, and it's not trivial.  i'll have to research/experiment to see if it's even feasible with just a `\tag` construction.  that may deserve a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The `leqno` option causes `\tag` to do what you describe:

```
\documentclass[leqno]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

short
\begin{equation}
\tag{XX} 1=2
\end{equation}

long
\begin{equation}
\tag{YY} 1=2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2+
2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not now that. But in my case, I need both variants in the same environment, sometimes even in the same line. Is that possible?

Comment: @JoachimBreitner anything is of course possible (you can always go into amsmath and pull out the definitions in the leqno case and copy them making a `\ltag` or whatever available even if right align is the default) But given the wording of barbara's question I suspect someone has already done that and she has an answer primed so ping her with a `@` comment on your question:-) –  David Carlisle 8 mins ago