# Vertically-centred left-hand identifier/'tag' in align(at) environment

Tags: equations, alignat

I'd like to reproduce the output seen below within the `alignat` environment:

[image: desired]

So essentially I'm looking for a way to have some identifier on the left and vertically centred (as MIP is here).  Sort of similar to the `\tag`s often found on the right hand side of the output. I would prefer to still be able to use those right-hand tags along with any solution, if that is possible.

Comment: Are you using `align` or `align*`? In other words, do you want numbers on the right or not?

Answer (score 2):

This solution uses `\reqnomode` and `\leqnomode` defined [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/193538/110998).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\leqnomode}{\tagsleft@true}
\newcommand{\reqnomode}{\tagsleft@false}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
% By default, labels are on the right-hand side
\leqnomode % switch to left-hand labels
\begin{align*}
  \max cx&+hy \\
       Ax&+Gy\leq b \tag{MIP}\\
        x&\geq0,\text{ $y\geq0$ and integer}
\end{align*}
\reqnomode % switch back to right-hand labels
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, if `(MIP)` is meant as a description, rather than as a tag.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
            &&  \max cx&+hy \\
\text{(MIP)}&&       Ax&+Gy\leq b \\
            &&        x&\geq0,\text{ $y\geq0$ and integer}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```