# How to make the citation beside the equation

Tags: equations, positioning, citing

I want to make the citation beside the equation at the same line contrary to this image, has any one any idea about that?

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{revtex4-1}% http://ctan.org/pkg/revtex4-1
\vspace{500px}
\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{1em}}  % Add a gap in the Contents, 
\begin{document}
where $\rho_{ij}$ is the stoichiometric coefficient of species $S_i$ which 
reacting in the system.
From the deterministic reaction rate $K_j$, the reaction rate $C_j$ can be 
obtained. For more details about calculating $C_j$ 
\cite{wolkenhauer04}\cite{gillespie07}.\\
 Assuming that the reaction has the form
\ce{S_1+4S_2 ->[c_j] P1+ P2} , $a_j(X)$ deduced as next: 
\[
a_j(X)=c_j.\binom{X_1}{1}.\binom{X_2}{4} = (c_1 \centerdot x_1).(\frac{1}
{4}).X_2.(X_2-1).(X_2-2).(X_2-3) 
\]~\cite{herajy13}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: i only want to writw the citation reference beside the equation at the same line not under it

Comment: Okay, then this will do the trick: `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
E=mc^2
\end{equation}
\end{document}`

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with calling `\cite` within a displayed equation. If, however, you want the citation flushed right, you may abuse the `\tag*` macro from `amsmath`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Consider
\[
a=b \tag*{from \cite{foo}}
\]
or
\begin{equation}
c=d \qquad \text{(see \cite{foo})}
\end{equation}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{foo} Foo, by Me Myself.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

IMNSHO the first form should be discouraged, as it may easily be mistaken for an equation number. At the very least some word (like "see", "cf." or "from" as in my example above) should be used.

If you prefer the citation on the left, you could use the solution proposed [in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/193538/82917).