# flalign, leqno and equations left aligned. Overlapping of equations and tags

Tags: amsmath, tag, flalign

I'm using flalign to align equations flush-left to the page margin.

I then stumbled on this [Switch between leqno and reqno options (of amsmath) in the same document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/193535/54807) and used it.

Now I have tags overlapping the equations. Notice that the room for tags is still to the right.

[image: Overlapping of tags and equations]

```
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{dsfont}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\leqnomode}{\tagsleft@true}
\newcommand{\reqnomode}{\tagsleft@false}
\makeatother

\leqnomode
\begin{flalign}
& \forall x, y(x,y\in\mathds{R}\Rightarrow x+y\in\mathds{R}) & P \\
& \forall x,y\left[ x,y\in\mathds{R}\Rightarrow x+y=y+x\right] & P \\
& \forall x,y,z\left[x,y,z\in\mathds{R}\Rightarrow(x+y)+z=x+(y+z)\right] & P
\end{flalign}
```

How can I have automatic and consistent spacing for tags exactly as if they were set to the default position (right)?

[image: Right tags not overlapping]

Comment: note the `fl` in `fleqn` means flush left but the `fl` in `flalign` does not: (it stands for full length: not a good name, but it is what it is)

Comment: Thanks :D. In fact in my document I'm occasionally using flalign to cover an entire line with flush-left formulas and flush-right text (P in this case) (without considering tags). In other occasions I'm using align to center the equations. The point is that I'd rather keep that layout but with tags on the left.

Answer (score 1):

`\newcommand{\leqnomode}{\tagsleft@true}` can't work, if given the `fleqn` option at load time `amsmath` uses *different definitions* for most of its environments. Just in a few simple cases (as shown in the linked answer) the same code is used for centred and flush left equations with a runtime `\iftagsleft@` test.

To allow switching in general you would need to copy the amsmath code so that it always loaded both centred and flush left versions, (under distinguished internal names, and then `\let` the public version of the environment to be either either the centred or flush left version depending on the style required at that point.

Answer (score 0):

In the place of the `flalign` environment, you can use a normal `align`, nested in the `fleq` environment from `nccmath`, which works temporarily like the `fleqn` option, and can take an optional argument: the distance of the equation left margin from the text left margin:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.3pt}
 \usepackage{amssymb, mathtools, nccmath} %
\usepackage{dsfont}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\leqnomode}{\tagsleft@true}
\newcommand{\reqnomode}{\tagsleft@false}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\leqnomode

\begin{fleqn}[2.5em]
\begin{align}
& \forall x, y(x,y\in\mathds{R}\Rightarrow x+y\in\mathds{R}) & P \\
& \forall x,y\left[ x,y\in\mathds{R}\Rightarrow x+y=y+x\right] & P \\
& \forall x,y,z\left[x,y,z\in\mathds{R}\Rightarrow(x+y)+z=x+(y+z)\right] & P
\end{align}
\end{fleqn}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This isn't very different from specifying a space manually before each line, is it?

Comment: I don't know the the internals of the environment, but I think it amounts to changing the value of `\displayindent` once and for all the environment.