# Change numbering from left to right

Tags: equations, enumerate, preamble

I am using the following preamble:

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{enumitem}
%\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\DeclareMathOperator{\ch}{char}
\usepackage[pagewise]{lineno}%\linenumbers
```

But in the text, the equation numbering appears on the left side. I want it to appear on the right side. What command can I use for this?

The following is happening:
[image]

I would like the "(9)" in the right side.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You should be generous enough to put a complete minimal compilable code that reproduces the output. Don't bet everyone would guess.

Comment: `\documentclass[reqno,12pt]{amsart}`

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/508064/change-equation-numbering-between-left-and-right?rq=1